# Can I add/retrieve/delete entries from Settings.NameValueTable content provider in android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I would like to store a pair of strings(name, value) to android's default content provider `Settings.NameValueTable`. 
Questions
1. Is is possible to access such provider?
2. If yes, any code examples I can follow? There are not many docs, even on android site about how to do changes to this `Settings.NameValueTable` provider. The only code snippet I could locate is for adding entries to contact providers.

Thanks!

Comment: 1.Add: `Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), "name", "valuesyouwant")`
2.Retrive `Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "name")`
3.Delete: well you can always overrite the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Add: `Settings.System.putString(getContentResolver(), "name", "valuesyouwant")`
2.Retrive `Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "name")`
3.Delete: well you can always overrite the val

Comment: Does this code seem to be reliable to use on 2.3.x android, 4.x android, 5.x android and on different vendors' devices, like samsung, HTC, Xiaomi etc?

Comment: It should also be noted that this action requires the following permission in the Android Manifest: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />`